# Problem with SVG image in QML

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, svg, qml

I use the QT5 from `ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper`. When trying to use a SVG as ab image source like

```
Image {
    source: "sample.svg"
    height: 100
    width: 100
}
```

I get the following error:

```
QML QQuickImage: Invalid image data: file:///home/***/sample.svg
```

I am relatively sure though that the demo I wrote at the end of January, that also uses SVG images, worked at that time.

Can anyone reproduce the error and should this be reported as a bug, and if so, where?

Comment: what happens if you use the sourceSize.width  and sourcesSize.height tags ?  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-image.html#sourceSize-prop  you also have libqt5svg5 and libqt5svg5-dev Installed ?

Comment: I have now both those packages installed and also added sourceSize.width: 100 and sourcesSize.height: 100 but I get the same error.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error and it also worked in January for me.

Comment: i think you should post your question on http://stackoverflow.com/. They can help you with programming problems

Comment: @Alen While this question could technically fit into [so], it is right here on [ubuntu.se]. Most Ubuntu Touch developers will keep an eye on the [tag:ubuntu-touch] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is, that the needed library was not packaged in the Qt 5.0.0 in `ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper`. In Qt 5.0.1, which is currently in the `ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta-proper` it works again.